# Mutinity with CompletableFuture throws an Exception that was losts

Tags: java, quarkus, java-11, mutiny

I'm using quarkus and i trying to call in asynchronous and reactive mode (using Mutinity) a CompletableFuture, which invokes parallel tasks inside it, calls to a remote rest api endpoint. I get an exception, I relaunch it (CompletionException) but the code continues in its execution, therefore the streamResult list will contain a null value and will go to nullpointer instead of returning the error and interrupting the execution. How can I do?

```
final Stream<DocumentUploadRequestResponse> streamResult = documents.stream().map(
        d -> Uni.createFrom().completionStage(
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                            try {
                                return myRestClientGeneratedClass.getXXX(bankId, d.getXXX(), language, outerHeaders);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new CompletionException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());//exception was eraised to container?
                            }
                }, managedExecutor)))
                .map(uni -> uni.await().atMost(Duration.ofMinutes(1)));

Map<UUID, List<DocumentStatusAndAttachedAttributesDto>>  checklistRequestDocumentsMap =  streamResult/*.filter(Objects::nonNull) -> this avoid nullpointer but it's not result that I want!*/
        .map(documentUploadRequest -> Map.entry(documentUploadRequest.getUuid(), documentUploadRequest.getDocuments()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

documentUploadRequest.getUuid() -> NullPointer Exception! instead an Http 404 bad Request!

Thanks

Roberto